# ¿Por qué Header muestra un espacio en blanco?

Tags: css

En el siguiente código:

```
header {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #65997d 10%, #fccb6e 90%);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Si quito el border aparece un espacio en blanco en el margen superior, ¿a qué se debe o qué está mal?

El css también incluye:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #ccc;

}

main, section, aside, footer {
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 0rem;
    /*border: 1px solid #000000;*/
    color: #bbb;
}

main {
    /* background: #000000; */
}
```

Comment: ¿A qué le aplicas ese estilo? ¿Será que a ese elemento del DOM le aplica otro estilo que define el border? Creo que es relevante añadir más info sobre el HTML correspondiente

Comment: Si lo que intentas es no tener el borde, prueba usando el siguiente codigo css: border: 0px solid red; (ya no tendras borde al tener un pixel de 0)

Comment: Sí lo intenté y vuelve a aparecer esa zona blanca en la parte superior. Como mejor queda es quitando el border y poniendo un padding, tambien desaparece lo blanco.